# Python - change a list column type without creating a new list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have lists within the list and for the third column in each sub-list I would like to change its value from String to Int, without creating additional new list (I would know how to do this if I declare new list `list2`) but to change it immediately within it (if possible).

```
list1=[[1,"a","100"],[2,"b","200"],[3,"c","300"]]    
[int(item[2]) for item in list1]                
for t in list1:
    print(type(t[2]))

<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

This prints `str`. The goals is to have integers.
Also I must use python 2.7 (can't upgrade to python 3)

The goal is to have list with all other columns:

```
list1=[[1,"a",100],[2,"b",200],[3,"c",300]]
```

Comment: You did not change the original list - `list`?!  How do you expect to see the changes? Try this `list1 = ....` and see if that's works.

Comment: Iterate over your list index wise and change the third entry of each element, and then assign that new entry to the old entries position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1=[[1,"a","100"],[2,"b","200"],[3,"c","300"]]
for x in list1:
    x[2] = int(x[2])
list1 # outputs [[1, 'a', 100], [2, 'b', 200], [3, 'c', 300]]
```